# Software for creating desktop application for Linux and Windows platforms

Tags: linux, web-apis, shopping

I want to create an app which runs on Linux and Windows-based terminals (or only Linux) like the one which we usually see in shopping malls to purchase some things yourself. I have written web APIs and hosted in IIS (Windows server). I need to build a UI which will call these APIs for data sharing.

Comment: Have you looked at electron? https://electronjs.org/

Comment: Yes. But can't go with it as we can't rely on the Web. Need to do as a desktop app

Comment: See this quesiton by the way: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2088/selecting-a-platform-for-developing-desktop-applications

Comment: If desktop app, you can still run web solution on your intranet. So web browser is interface on the desk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a [list of platform-independent GUI libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_platform-independent_GUI_libraries) on Wikipedia.

Some of them are fairly modern and relatively popular:

- [Xamarin.Forms](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/) with C# as a default programming language. I assume you're familiar with C#, based on IIS comment.
- [OpenJFX](https://openjfx.io/) (Java and JVM-based languages)
- [Qt](https://www.qt.io/) (C++)

By the way, take a closer look on @minboost's suggestion in the comments. [Electron](https://electronjs.org/) is also a framework for full-fledged desktop applications, althogh it uses technologies (JavaScript, HTML, CSS) typically associated with web products.